# htaccess rule to Redirect 404 to 301?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am using htaccess rule to redirect from old direction to new directory. For this I have used this Rules in my htaccess file of WordPress.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/leffa-aineistot/(.+)$ /$1
```

It works fine in all case like url `example.com/leffa-aineistot/xyz` redirect fine to `example.com/xyz`

Now I have changed one directory name from `yyy` and `yyy1` and the following rules does  not redirect to `yyy1`
It always redirect to `yyy` which is 404 page error and not found.

How can I redirect `example.com/some/xyz` to `example.com/xyz1`

I am using this in WordPress.

Any help in this redirect would be highly appriciated.

htaccess file codes

```
RewriteOptions inherit
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~whkinghillfi/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . /~whkinghillfi/index.php [L]
# END WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RedirectMatch 301 ^/leffa-aineistot/(.+)$ /$1
```

Adding the complete code of htaccess file for better understanding.
[image]

Comment: Could you please confirm if `xyz`(which could be any value, I understand) should be rewritten to always `xyz1` I mean only `1` should be added with xyz(or any other value)? Kindly confirm it once.

Comment: @anubhava This is my main url https://warehouse.kinghill.fi/leffa-aineistot/sffilm and I want to redirect to https://warehouse.kinghill.fi/sfstudios/ . Hope it is more clear.

And htaccess rule now redirect to https://warehouse.kinghill.fi/sffilm/ which is 404 page

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 This is my main url https://warehouse.kinghill.fi/leffa-aineistot/sffilm and I want to redirect to https://warehouse.kinghill.fi/sfstudios/ . Hope it is more clear.

And htaccess rule now redirect to https://warehouse.kinghill.fi/sffilm/ which is 404 page

Comment: @DeepakLakhara, Good that you have shown us your htaccess rule file, could you please post it as text form, images or links not encouraged since we can't copy/paste them and test it, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have added htaccess code now. Hope you got my issue and will help me to fix this.

Comment: Why do you have `RedirectMatch 301 ^/leffa-aineistot/(.+)$ /$1` ? That is the rule doing `warehouse.kinghill.fi/sffilm` redirect

Comment: @anubhava Yes, this is correct. It redirects to as you said. It was in old site and in new hosting it is changed the name of sffilm to sfstudios . So Which rule or code should I apply to achieve this. warehouse.kinghill.fi/sffilm this is 404 page because there is no site with name sffilm and i want sffilm to redirect on sfstudios.

Comment: Then please show your latest and most current .htaccess that is not working for you

Comment: @anubhava This is the latest one. I am asking which rule should i write to redirect from  warehouse.kinghill.fi/leffa-aineistot/sffilm to warehouse.kinghill.fi/sfstudios Because I have no idea about writting rules

Comment: ok comment out `RedirectMatch` line and insert `RewriteRule ^leffa-aineistot/sffilm/?$ /sfstudios [L,NC,R=301]` just below `RewriteBase` line.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks it works like charms but I have some another url like this https://warehouse.kinghill.fi/leffa-aineistot/disney -> https://warehouse.kinghill.fi/disney which stopped working after commenting the previous condition. How Do I achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Comment out your `RedirectMatch` directive as that is just removing `/leffa-aineistot` from all URLs.

**Just below `RewriteBase` line**, you can insert specific redirect rule first before using a generic redirect rule later:

```sh
# specific redirect
RewriteRule ^leffa-aineistot/sffilm/?$ /sfstudios [L,NC,R=301]

# generic redirect
RewriteRule ^leffa-aineistot/(.+)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @anubhava @RavinderSingh13 for helping on this topic.
I resolved this using multiple redirect rules in htaccess and worked well.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/leffa-aineistot/sffilm/?$ /sfstudios [L,NC,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/leffa-aineistot/disney/?$ /disney [L,NC,R=301]
```